# DAX formula to calculate min/max within period

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

i have a following power pivot.

1. How could I find Min and Max values in 2021 and 2022?
2. And also Min and Max values within each month

[pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvSh9.png)

Comment: Have you tried munifs() and maxifs() ?

Comment: Put the field in the values area two more times and set the function to Min and Max respectively.